# How to interact Dapp with MobileWallet

Tags: react-redux, ethereum, web3js

I'm building a dapp application on Ethereum using React & Web3js. As usual the dapp will get the injected provider from Window.web3 (MetaMask), perhaps. The problem that I'm facing now is how can I allow other mobile wallet to sign and access my dapp? For example, CryptoKitties & DDEX Exchange platform.

```
import Web3 from "web3"

var  web3 = null
if (typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined') {
      window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
      web3 =new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider)
    } else {
      web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://user01.blockchain.azure.com:3200/xxxxx"));
    }

export default web3;
```